SwiftUI ScrollView has weird behavior when reseting the content
I'm working with SwiftUI and trying to do a ScrollView that can be filtered (it's basically a list).
The stack looks like this:
class ViewModel: ObservableObject {
    @Published
    var isRefreshing = false
    var components: [Int] = Array(0...100)
    
    func refresh() {
        isRefreshing = true
        DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 1) {
            self.isRefreshing = false
        }
    }
}



struct ContentView: View {
    @StateObject
    private var viewModel: ViewModel

    init() {
        _viewModel = StateObject(wrappedValue: ViewModel())
    }
    
    var body: some View {
        ScrollView(showsIndicators: false) {
            LazyVStack(spacing: .zero, pinnedViews: [.sectionHeaders]) {
                Section {
                    if viewModel.isRefreshing {
                        loadingView
                    } else {
                        ForEach(viewModel.components, id: \.hashValue) { _ in
                            Rectangle()
                                .frame(height: 700)
                                .foregroundStyle(Color.blue)
                                .padding(.bottom, 24)
                        }
                    }
                } header: {
                    filterBar
                        .onTapGesture {
                            viewModel.refresh()
                        }
                }
            }
        }
    }
    
    var filterBar: some View {
        Rectangle()
            .foregroundStyle(Color.yellow)
            .frame(height: 100)
    }
    
    var loadingView: some View {
        Rectangle()
            .foregroundStyle(Color.green)
            .frame(height: 300)
    }
}

In resume we have two possible states: loading or content. When applying filters we first change the status to loading. This replaces the ForEach with a static LoadingView. Then after the network request finishes we replace the LoadingView with the ForEach again.
Most of the time this works fine. But there are a few times where the LoadingView is not displayed. Instead the whole View is blank (I just see the background). Sometimes it disappears once the content is refreshed but others it gets stuck on this blank content until the user starts scrolling again.
The recording shows the issue. We scroll the view a little bit and then tap the filter. Instead of displaying the loading it just gets all blank. Sometimes it works fine.

The example above was simplified as much as I could. Still the problem persists. Trying to scroll back to the top didn't solve the issue as well as the blank background continues to appear from time to time.
By looking at the Visual Debugger, the ScrollView is there with correct width and height. But the content just isn't at view port.

You are misusing ObservedObject look at the documentation for ObservedObject and StateObject

Indeed StateObject can be used in the sample. But the issue happens even while using it. I updated the sample.

Using the memberwise initializer is explicitly discouraged. Look at the documentation for both closely.

I replaced the initializer. Can confirm that the ViewModel is not being recreated but the issue persists.

"But there are a few times where the LoadingView is not displayed." What is "a few times"? Can you reliably reproduce this? What steps did you take to reproduce this?

Yes, I can reliably reproduce it. With this exact setup it happened way less (maybe one time in over 30-40 tries). But it still happens. In the original project which has more complex content than Rectangles it happens pretty often (like 30% of the time). Trying to filter on different scroll positions make it more likely for the issue to happen.

Is it normal that your array of components is not published ?

In the original app it's published as well as there is pagination. In the sample it doesn't matter as I just want to change between the array and loading status.

For what its worth I cant reproduce it (green block always shows and blue always loads) tried preview and ios 17.5 simulator.
